# React HighChart, apply different gradient color for each dataset

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, gradient

I have a highchart table, I want to apply a gradient for underneath the graph line for each data set. Each data set already has the line coloured differently, but it seems impossible to apply a gradient color for each dataset.

I cannot apply `areaSpline` for each `series` of the chart:

```
 c.series?.forEach((s, index) => {
    s.type = 'areaspline';
    s.color = colors.spline[index];
  });

  c.chart = { type: 'areaspline' };
  c.plotOptions = {
    series: {
      stacking: isStacked ? 'normal' : undefined,
      connectNulls: true,
      marker: {
        enabled: false,
        radius: 14,
      },
    },
    areaspline: {
      // fillOpacity: 0.5,
      fillColor: {
        linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
        stops: [
          [0, 'red'],
          [1, 'transparent'],
        ],
      },
    },
  };
```

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the gradient for each series, not in `plotOptions`. For example:

```
  series: [{
    ...,
    fillColor: {
      linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
      stops: [
        [0, 'blue'],
        [1, 'transparent'],
      ]
    }
  }, {
    ...,
    fillColor: {
      linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
      stops: [
        [0, 'red'],
        [1, 'transparent'],
      ]
    }
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kczgb4Lv/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.areaspline.fillColor

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know why, maybe it's a versioning thing, but I cannot apply fillColor to series. 

Type '{ data: string[]; fillColor: { linearGradient: { x1: number; x2: number; y1: number; y2: number; }; stops: [number, string][]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'SeriesOptionsType'.

Comment: Hi @Edoardo Trotta, With typescript, you need to also set `type` for each series.